# Issue with Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 Pro N Version 22H2

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code (VS Code) on my Windows 10 Pro N system, version 22H2. Despite meeting the system requirements and using the latest version of VS Code, I am experiencing difficulties with updates and security fixes.

Upon launching VS Code, I received a message indicating that support for certain Windows versions has ended and that updates may no longer be available for my system. However, my understanding is that Windows 10 Pro N version 22H2 is still supported by VS Code.

I can't even open terminal of vs code properly

Steps Taken:

- Checked for updates: Ensured that I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code by going to Help > Check for Updates.
- Reinstalled Visual Studio Code: Uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code to troubleshoot any potential issues with the installation.
- Verified system requirements: Confirmed that my system meets the minimum requirements for running Visual Studio Code.
- Updated Windows: Ensured that my Windows 10 Pro N system is up to date with the latest updates from Microsoft.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should at least include the version number in case it really is some old version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) give the _exact_ error/warning message. 2) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.